# Rare document reads bug with firebase, react and redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux-saga

I'm trying to get some documents from firebase using redux-saga for the async functions. I'm using `useEffect` hook on my component to send the start actions:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      fetchUnfilteredAsyncStart(); // start action saga 1
      storeAvailableTagsStart(); // start action saga 2
  }, [fetchUnfilteredAsyncStart, storeAvailableTagsStart]);
```

All good here, now the two saga functions:

```
// saga 1
function* fetchUnfilteredAsync() {
  // first document
  const articlesRef = db
    .collection('articles_september')
    .orderBy("date_db", "desc")
    .limit(1);
  // inital fetch from firebase
  try {
    const res = yield articlesRef.get({ source: "server" })
      .then((snapshot) => {
      // storing last element from collection
      const lastRef = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
      const articles = [];
      snapshot.forEach((article) =>
        articles.push([article.data(), article.id])
      );
      return [articles, lastRef];
    });
    // firing success actions to store data on reducer
    yield put(fetchUnfilteredArticlesSuccess(res[0]));
    yield put(storeLastUnfilteredElement(res[1]));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(fetchUnfilteredArticlesFailure(error));
  }
}
```

---

```
// saga 2
function* storeAvailableTagsAsync() {
  // second document
  const tagsRef = db.doc(`available_tags/wAAVxYZYRYjqdLGXa1kn`);

  try {
    const res = yield tagsRef.get({ source: "server" }).then((doc) => {
      return doc.data().available_tags;
    });

    yield put(storeAvailableTagsSuccess(res));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(storeAvailableTagsFailure(error));
  }
}
```

A pretty basic use of the `get()` method. My problem is that every time I run my development server `npm start` for the first time I get 16 document reads on firebase, when I should be getting only 2. The funny part is that after the `npm start` every time I refresh the page I get the 2 reads I should be getting since the start. Even when I do a hard refresh, I'm still getting 2 reads, but if I stop the server and restart it, I get 16 reads again! Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having a similiar issue, I solved it, my redux-saga was all good, my problem was that everytime I ran my development server, I opened Firebase too. That means that I wasn't counting the reads everytime I opened my Firebase console over and over again :)